# Can we do anything better about users under 13?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, deleted-users

Currently to comply with US law ([COPPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act)) moderators are told to report any accounts of users under 13 to the CM team for a super special deletion to comply with this law.

I do this as required, but every time it comes up I hate myself a little for having to do it. There are some really smart 11 year old kids out there and we should be encouraging and nurturing them. It seems manifestly wrong to me that we seek to extinguish the spark of enthusiasm in the brightest and best kids of the next generation as a matter of policy.

I'm not a lawyer and I appreciate the complexities and importance of compliance here, but there's got to be a better way. Some random ideas:

1. Add a parental consent mechanism? The Wikipedia article seems to imply that this would be sufficient for compliance.
2. Add another account type that collects less info?
3. Lobby for law changes?

Please can SE do something to make the current situation where we're figuratively crushing the hopes and dreams of kids just a little bit better?

Comment: In keeping with the "don't ask, don't tell" philosophy that we appear to have a the moment, rather than adding a parental consent step at sign up would be be easier to make it part of the "COPPA deletion" process? i.e. the first step is to ask for parental consent, then if it's not forthcoming delete the account?

Comment: A user with a Bender gravatar is worried about crushing the hopes and dreams of children? You should get yourself checked, man. No, seriously - yeah. Sounds like a good thing to think about.

Comment: This is wild speculation since I don't know about the law, but can't you create a system where you mark the account as a 'child account', rename it temporarily to something silly (if generating silly names is difficult, ask Boltclock the Unicorn, who has demonstrated experience), record the date at which the user reaches age 13, remove email addresses and any law-violating personal information from their profile, lock down everything in their profile from being changed until they reach 13, and then reach out to them letting them pick a new (obviously not real) username if they like?

Comment: No, keep the little tykes away from the site.  There are much better things for 13-year olds to be doing than sitting indoors squinting at a computer screen.  Do you want (yet another) generation of hunch-backed, short-sighted, muscle-wasted children turning into pasty, chair-bound, always-Twittering adults ?

Comment: 'manifestly wrong' yes, it is wrong but nobody has come up with a better system yet.  Hard age limits are set in law for other activities and ,eveven though we probably both know 'underage' people who are skilled, knowledgeable and mature enough to drive cars, drink alcohol, have sex, sign up for the armed services of their country etc, they legally cannot.  I can't see any way round such limits that would be lawyer-proof, (my opinion, IANAL), and I'm sure that this 'exceptions' issue has been gone over in those other areas too.

Comment: You make it sound as though "sitting indoors squinting at a computer screen" is this generations' *choice*, @HighPerformanceMark, rather than the consequence of adults trying to stop them from doing pretty much anything else out of fear for their safety. In an age where parents can be jailed for letting their kids play in a park unsupervised, the accessibility of Stack Overflow is hardly the thing keeping them indoors. Let's give these kids as much freedom as we can get away with, and let them make the best of the choices they have available to them - not make the problem worse.

Comment: Having SE solve this problem so that parental consent is meaningfully implemented would solve a lot of other problems as well.  The mods would have a lot less work having to deal with fraudulent accounts in general.  They however seem to be *very* reluctant to move away from OpenID.  The $16,000 coppa fine isn't scary enough perhaps.  Or they just rely on you always following the rulez.

Comment: "There are some really smart 11 year old kids out there and we should be encouraging and nurturing them." Absolutely - I'd rather have these *proven* enthousiasts contributing to SO, over the regular daily flurry of ["ascii codec can't decode byte 0x92"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36496175/2564301) and ["I got the below error while starting the hue server"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36495915/2564301).

Comment: I relatively regularly see kids under 15 ask questions eons above what some _adults_ decide is worth putting on the site. I agree with this.

Comment: @RadLexus: While I agree, the legal obstacle course you'd have to navigate to properly allow users under 13 to use your site might still outweigh the benefit of implementing something to verify a user's age. Don't ask, don't tell / remove on sight might simply be more efficient in allowing as many users as possible to use the site.

Comment: While I agree kids should generally spend less time with electronic devices than many of them do nowadays, Stack Overflow keeping under-13 year olds out is not going to change any of that one iota.

Comment: @ChrisF: On a site I used to administrate, we immediately suspended underage users, with a message asking for either parental consent, or a (censored) copy of some kind of legal ID that contains their name, photo and DOB. When either was provided, the account could be unbanned. I've rarely ever seen any form of parental consent (Although that may be related to the site having a "adult" section). The consent is nearly impossible to verify, as well.

Comment: Tell politicians to stop micromanaging our lives?

Comment: new site: SO4Kidz

Comment: It would be interesting to know what children focused computer clubs do: https://www.codeclub.org.uk/ . Certainly many agencies need to store information regarding children in a secure / very well considered etc etc manner - can SO get the accreditation (if this is a thing) to do so? It would be such a shame to put off the future talent. Here is the advice for schools relating to the "Data Protection Act" from the "Information Commissioners Office": https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/education/

Comment: I assume you "discover" the age from the birthday given in the profile. It's unclear whether that information is legally binding, I can write anything there. That said, any of the mentioned "really smart 11 year old kids" should be able to figure out the solution to this problem, since the birthday field is optional.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If there's a child who's smart and articulate enough to be truly contributing to StackExchange, then *yes*, I absolutely want them to be on the computer more! Being a part of this community is a sign of incredible maturity and intelligence, arguably even for adults, and a child who can contribute here will learn a lot from the experience. Besides, using a computer and being physically active are not mutually exclusive. I can tell you that from personal experience. Growing up, I spent hours every week on the computer but also went running with my parents regularly.

Comment: @Jester the smart ones usually do figure out that fairly quickly, but they still write comments or link to twitter...

Comment: I think HPM's comment was more tongue-in-cheek than anything else, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: That is what happened to me when I asked a question yesterday. I was served with a message from a user saying that I should be 13 or over or something along those lines.

Comment: If my account gets deleted I will be very disappointed, because although I am under the age of 13, I feel I adhere to the standards and policies expected by SO.

Comment: @Bruno - I get the impression it's out of the hands of SO since it's purely a legal issue.  You may want to officially change your account to be "owned" by your parents...

Comment: @Chris How can I do that?

Comment: @Bruno: As Chris mentioned, this is purely a legal issue. How to do that can be answered by one of the mods currently active on this question. Maybe ping Brad Larson on your answer here, asking for advice on providing parental consent.

Comment: Without any references that specify someone's age, it's impossible to tell. Normally I'd say to just never mention your age online. Ever. It should never matter - how you carry yourself and treat others is what matters. In your case though, I'd suggest reaching out to a mod directly for advice.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Just in case your comment was not sarcastic, I play sports and actually spend more time outdoors than I do in front of my computer. Programming is just one of my many hobbies, not my only one.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think i'll do just that.

Comment: Nope, my comment wasn't sarcastic or tongue in cheek.  I like to work in a child-free zone, same as I like to drink in pubs which don't allow children.  Don't fret too much though, mine is just one voice among many and I don't expect that SO or SE will change their policies or behaviours on my account.  The long and the short of it is that I entirely support SE's adherence to laws (and anything else) which have the effect of keeping children out of the workplace.

Comment: Would you work in a company founded by a kid? My point is it depends on the way the person regardless of age behaves. I am sure there are more people on here over 18 that act like kids than there are kids that act like kids.

Comment: @Bruno: He's messing with you.

Comment: @Bruno You've got a bright future ahead of you. If this ends up going south, and the (antiquated) laws force SO to nuke your account... don't give up. Come back when you're 13, and ask your parents to make posts on your behalf in the meantime. I'm just a few years older than you are; you're way ahead of where I was at your age. Don't let the law slow you down, just accept it as an unfortunate side-effect of the legal system and work around it.

Comment: @Undo Thank you. I think i'll do just that.

Comment: My son (who was <13 when he signed up - shock horror) seemed to quickly work out without any suggestion from me that he simply need not tell the site he was under 13. Perhaps this should just be some sort of test of common sense (which clearly US law lacks).

Comment: @abligh *'Why do they bother putting age restrictions on these things when all you have to do is click "Yes, I am 18"? Even a 17 year old can figure that out.'* - House, from the TV show of the same name.

Comment: I think it all depends on the content rating. If the content is deemed suitable for such ages then I think you're better off treating them as any other user.

Comment: @Flexo I just found a user today that admitted they were under age for the site.  Should I mod flag something like that or leave it alone and someone at some point in time finds it?

Comment: @NathanOliver As usual don't go out of your way to hunt for stuff to flag. If you do stumble across users who you believe really are under 13 then feel free to flag in line with your legal and moral obligations.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks.  Seems to be the advice I get from everyone.

Comment: If we don't help kids here, they'll find places elsewhere, to pose their questions. Places that are less quality and less safe than Stackoverflow. Voted +1

Answer (score 126):

As [Cerbrus said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320667/50049), it's purely a legal issue. We're not allowed to collect and store any personally-identifying information about minors under the age of 13 without explicit parental consent.

If it's discovered that someone is under 13, we:

- Send them a courtesy email letting them know that we have to remove their account, and why. We also strongly encourage them to come back once they turn 13, and place heavy emphasis on the fact that they didn't do anything wrong. We encourage them to keep going with what they're doing. This is not a canned email, a community manager writes something every time.
- Sometimes get a response *from the parent*, and we instruct the parent on how *they* can have an account, and post questions for their child as needed. But, it's the *parent's* information we're collecting.

While I *really* wish we had the resources to set up a department that just kept track of parental consent and users under 13, *when* they turn 13 and everything else - we simply don't. That's why we have to purge those accounts when we find them.

We can't really do much more than we do for anonymous use of the site beyond simply reading it. The number of cases of cookie-only accounts on Stack Overflow inundated our support department so strongly that we had to require registration in order to ask a question - that many people were losing the cookie and becoming disenfranchised from their accounts. This meant they couldn't comment, so they wrote answers. Or they'd suggest edits to their own questions or answers, it was a mess. We need *something* tying you to an account to offer any hopes of recovering it.

I *wish* we didn't have to do it, but being the parent of two kids under 13 and a former programmer that's well aware of the scum-baggery that junk sites delight in delving into .. I appreciate what the law was trying to accomplish. It doesn't stop kids from being tricked into giving this information to sleazy outfits that abuse it, but it makes what those sleazy outfits are doing a crime - something that comes with consequences, and that's something I appreciate.

---

***Update:***

It doesn't matter where our servers are located. What matters is where we're incorporated. We're a US corporation, and we have to follow the law.

Comment: @canon We could, but they couldn't use the account any longer, and there'd be no way to recover it. Effectively, they'd be locked out of it. Personally-identifying information is stuff like your real name, email - anything unique about you that can identify you out of a crowd of many other visitors.

Comment: @canon My personal opinion only - I think laws around this are starting to smell antiquated. The _intent_ isn't, but there could be infrastructure to alleviate companies from becoming custodians of records. What if my 10 year old wanted to ask a question about Python, and I got a notification on my phone, used my password and allowed the account creation? I'm dreaming a bit here, but kids want Internet stuff way before 13 these days.

Comment: ... and yet ad networks can collect all the data they like with impunity. Thanks lawyers.

Comment: @Flexo "Why do mommy and daddy drink, and keep mumbling something about a hosts file and iptables while I use my tab?" - This could be a best-selling children's book, I'm just _sayin'_.

Comment: "In the great green hosts file there was a cellphoneincentives.com and a redsheriff.com and a twitpic.com adserver jumping over the mobicow.com ..." ([source](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/))

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for referencing mine :-) I know the feeling. Having to remove accounts for legal _<redacted>_ like this is no fun.

Comment: *"Send them a courtesy email letting them know that we have to remove their account"* - Why don't you just suspend the account for 1 or 2 years? (until he completes 13 years old)

Comment: @Zanon They'd still have the information collected from a user under 13, and that's the illegal part. (From my understanding.) The kid using the site isn't a big deal- SO can't prevent anonymous 13 year olds from browsing, for instance. It's when personal info is collected (such as the email used to login) that there's a problem. Suspending the user doesn't remove that personal information.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you discover that some user is under 13. Only from their profile information, I guess?

Comment: @ForceBru I believe many child less than 13 years old may be naive and simply *tell* you their age (like, *sry, I don't understand when you say "...". I'm only X<13 years old*).

Comment: I think this is a parental issue and shouldn't be a legal one or an SO issue.

Comment: This is a good balance that follows the law and places the responsibility on the parents.

Comment: @TimPost "Starting to smell antiquated" is an understatement. They were ill conceived when they were created. Basically it's telling kids under 13 that you have to lie about your age to join facebook (or whatever the kids are into nowadays). Note that not joining is often not seen as an option if you don't want to be seen as a square kid.

Comment: Would it make sense to make a way to tie the purged account to the parent's account so that they could reallocate it to their kid once the kid is old enough?  This would allow purging of the child's information but would still allow it to be reclaimed when they are old enough.

Comment: So... the solution is to base the company somewhere in the fiji islands. Right?

Answer (score 32):

This is purely a legal issue. Kids won't stop using the internet if their accounts are removed.

As site, you have 2 options:

- Prove you're doing *anything* and *everything* possible to verify the user's age *and* parental consent in case they're under 13.
- Make sure you remove users under the age border as soon as possible, when found out.

The first option is practically impossible to implement in a way that doesn't remove most of the functionality of the site, but still holds up in court.
The latter option is relatively easy to implement, and doesn't require sites to verify the age of *every single user*. It just means you have to remove users where there is a reasonable suspicion they're underage.

Since SO's "Terms of Service" (that *every* user agrees with) already [contains a rule](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/#1AccesstotheServices) stating a user must be at least 13 years of age, any user that's registered to SO is either 13+, or lied about their age. As far as I'm aware, SO can't legally be held responsible for users lying about their age. SO can only be held responsible if they *don't* remove users that turn out to be younger.

In the end, the *"Don't ask, Don't tell"* approach means a lot *more* underage users / developing* talents are able to use SO, as properly verifying their age is a pain in the butt.

And trust me, SO doesn't joke around about this. I once jokingly stated I was 12, in a chat room. That very nearly cost me my account.

<sup><sup>*Pun? where?</sup></sup>

Comment: -1 for lack of citations for the legal claims here. You're boldly asserting what the site's options are, and for all I know you may be *right*, but you haven't provided any evidence that would let someone not already versed in the relevant law to know whether you are or not.

Comment: Most of this is based on my experience administrating a US-based website that _also_ has adult content. I must admit I don't know the exact laws word-by-word. Just the practical implications. The point is: Either verify the user's age or parental consent, or get rid of underage users ASAP if you don't want legal trouble. That just reminded me of something I've edited in.

Comment: So, are you going to delete my account now? This seems unfair.

Comment: @Bruno: It may be unfair, but that's the result of COPPA. It's devilishly tricky to get the consent thing sorted.

Comment: I'll repeat myself from another comment. This is a parental issue and shouldn't be a legal one or an SO issue.

Comment: Tell that to the people that made up COPPA, @Rob. For SO, it's a legal issue. If they don't abide by COPPA, they're in legal trouble.

Comment: @Bruno: for what it's worth, there are some adults who haven't forgotten the things like this that our society did to them at a younger age, and are actively trying to fix it. Whether you can get parental consent worked out with stackoverflow or not, don't ever stop coding. And later, when it looks like the world might change about this, come out and help change it, along with the other folks who followed the path you're on. As someone further down that path, it only gets more amazing.

Answer (score 28):

I am not sure if this question is a result of my question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471728/methods-to-learn-full-stack-development

As you can see, I got this response in the comments

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age. No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address)

I understand that there are rules that every website has that everyone who subscribes to it has to follow, but I feel it would be quite sad if my account got closed because of a trivial matter such as this.

I provided my email address, which is actually one I use strictly for signing up for websites so I don't see a risk in it. My parents actually have access to my email address that I use to signup to websites so they can keep an eye on things too.

I enjoy learning on this website and I don't see what issues there could be. If my account gets closed, I can just create a new one can't I?

Comment: It's not just you. There have been multiple instances in the last week alone where someone identified themselves as being under the age of 13. None of the moderators are happy to report this when brought to our attention. We are aware of the law and of Stack Exchange's obligations, but I still remember having to report the account of one of the best contributors in the [kinect] tag because he stated he was underage in a comment. That made me very sad.

Comment: Maybe SO can have a word filter in the comments and question boxes to search for "age" and "years old" and provide a warning to user not to mention age ;)

Comment: Keep in mind: Don't ask, don't tell. SO can't know you're 13 if you don't tell them. No-one is going to sue you for lying about your age (On sites like SO, at least). SO _could_ get sued, on the other hand, if they don't remove the account. (I'd be a horrible parent :P)

Comment: I understand the issue better now.

Comment: @BradLarson It was suggested in one of the above answers that I may need to get my parents to be the "official" owners of my SO account. How can I go about doing this and getting their consent?

Comment: @Bruno: 1. ask your parents to sign up to Stack Overflow. Explain why it's important to you. 2. Ask SO to transfer your account to the new one. 3. *profit* - well, no. But then all questions (and answers) you have are legally attributable to your parents.

Comment: I was one of those 11-year-oldcomputer geeks like you, long before SO. I hope SO can come up with a way to work around COPPA to keep you with us. I suppose getting permission from your parents is your part of the bargain.

Comment: @ RadLexus Then transfer it back afterwards? (cc: @Bruno)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: after reaching the legal minimum age, you mean? Sure - why not.

Comment: @Bruno: I started "programming" when I was 10 and now I'm a (newly-promoted) Senior Software Engineer in my mid-20's, but a quick glance at your SO profile shows me you're already much, *much* further in your understanding than I was at your age.  That being said just like it's hard to write bullet-proof code (which is executed by computers) that has absolutely no bugs in it, it's hard to write bullet-proof laws (which are executed by people) that has no absolutely no "bugs" in it.

Comment: And just like code where we prioritize bugs and fix the worse ones first, we prioritize laws and fix people suffering the most.  Yes, this sucks, especially when you're on the receiving end of something like this (similarly you're probably been bored out of your mind if you go to a public or private school for your mandatory education requirement) but there are arguably more important bugs in our law.

Comment: If you feel passionate about equality or justice for humans you might consider law or politics - I think we need more people who are analytical there.  However nothing wrong with being *anything else* either you want to - your life is yours alone to live as you alone live with your decisions and you should choose your path yourself (and you don't have to decide on a profession, yet - in 3rd grade I wanted to be a programmer, but that changed a lot after that before I ended up being a CS major roughly mid-way through sophomore year in college).

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I fully understand the reasons behind the law after having spoken to my parents last night about this. I guess it is better it is enforced and some people suffer as a result than if it is non-existent and a lot of people suffer. I may be a little naive about the implications but I am willing to accept what comes. My parents just created an account on SO and I will try persuade the moderators to transfer my account over to theirs now.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I am not sure about law or politics but I definitely want to do something in aviation someday. Everything about that industry fascinates me and if I don't become a pilot, I would atleast like to become an engineer of sorts! Or I would like to become a professional BS-buster, i'll call myself BS-man and just pop up when I overhear some BS. Cape 'n all haha. Thanks for the advice Jared, I appreciate it very much :)

Comment: @Bruno Being a pilot, in general, in any country would have stringent health and fitness requirements and just like you're "too young" for this site, there might be something silly that disqualifies you you have no control over - like being too tall by half an inch.  Point being don't have your hopes up too high for that occupation, since there's so much luck (i.e. dependency on what you don't control) involved in attaining it.

Comment: I would recommend learning those options and requirements for each now and doing your best to prepare for them (including accepting your inability if you can't qualify on the basis of something health-related - and being prepared that you might one day be diagnosed with something out of the blue at the last second).  I'm not trying to dissuade you from trying - follow your dreams - just make sure you take the steps to make it a reality.

(Also even if you end up an engineer, either way you could make a YouTube channel that tells the adventures of BS-man and it might be a hit!)

Comment: That is a very good point! My parents tell me to just do different things I like and have fun doing them and worry about what I want to be one day only before I go to college. So hopefully, by the time I reach college, I would like one of these things enough to decide to do it professionally. I, however take your point, because it is very similar to what my parents said when I wanted to become a professional soccer player haha.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how I can get a moderator's attention? I had my parents open an account and emailed them through the contact form and they have heard nothing back. They also created an account and requested a profile merge but it seems the merge always deletes the newer account.

Answer (score 17):

I was a young computer geek once. With respect, I think it's part of the mission of SO to help people develop in this great trade of programming, regardless of situation. I know I understand it to be part of my personal mission.

I get that it's expensive to obtain and validate parental consent, and that you all have a business to run.

So, I have a suggestion: solicit community assistance with this:

- Add a kids' moderator or two.
- Make sure those people have had CORI checks for kids' safety. All schoolteachers and most youth workers have had those.
- When an underage person signs up, refer it to a kids' moderator, who can then work with parents to get written consent and file it at SOHQ.
- keep kids out of chat.
- give the kids' moderators a queue to pay attention to the activity of their charges. Maybe an automatic flag, visible only to kids mods, on every underage post?
- if things get out of hand, moderators can intervene. That's no different from how things work today.

Consider getting a foundation grant to help finance this. Gates Foundation?

Recruit some schoolteachers and other volunteers to be kids mods. (I'm willing, personally.)

Look, the no-kids response to COPPA is a safe-harbor response. Knocking off any youngster's account is a way to guarantee the company's safety. It doesn't guarantee kids' safety, because there's no way of verifying age.

But sometimes a mission involving education isn't perfectly safe. I hope you'll consider this.

Comment: While it's hard to disagree with your sentiments, it sounds to me you are inviting [guide me how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36516044/2564301) to add "im underage plzzz help me" to their questions ...

Comment: No, @RadLexus, I'm not offering more handholding. Quite the opposite. I'm suggesting that younguns on SO will be treated exactly the same as everybody else. Silly and unhelpful posts will get down voted and put on hold just like they do for the rest of us. Posts where they reveal unsafe personal stuff will get concealed.

Comment: Oh dear... kids moderators? Surely, you wouldn't want to see people like me being squashed under a blue diamond...

Comment: This is a really good answer, but one thing; "keep kids out of chat" seems wrong to me. For example, the user BRUNO, who is underage,  had his last question closed. One of the comments said that he should ask that question in chat, and mostly will get an answer there, as those kind of questions are valid in chat. So I think underage users should be allowed in chat.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ You make a good point about access to all the facilities. The reason I suggested keeping kids out of chat is purely for safety. I have some experience working with kids, and I know chat sessions can go from professional to personal very fast. And, sometimes the personal stuff is far more personal than it should be. That being said, I don't insist on the chat restriction.

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible to have a 'joined account'.  An adult can register their child, sans PI stuff.  The child can then post etc. within the adult's account.

Alternatively, what PI do you collect?  Can we have a reduced account for children?

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: provide for a mechanism to recover the account when the age of 13 is reached.

While it may be necessary for legal reasons to remove all personal information *now*, all information that gets deleted can be saved prior to the deletion and sent to the user. If it's saved in some way that allows it to later be re-imported into the system, then let the user hold on to the information. Provide instructions on how the user can contact you and send back the account data upon reaching the age of 13.

This may not be that useful for someone who's only 10, but it could make a huge difference for someone whose account gets deleted at 12 years and 11 months.

Comment: This would mean to keep the data... which is illegal. The law is the law is the law... I think a reduced data account or shared parent etc. account is the best way to go.

Comment: @Warpzit No, it wouldn't need SO to keep the data. That's the whole point. Export it, send it to the user, let the user keep it. It's not illegal for the user to keep the information. Then allow the user to send it back to SO when the user turns 13. (Obviously with some form of digital signature or encryption to prevent tampering.)

Comment: Sorry was too fast. But that seems like more hazzle than actually solving the problem properly.

Comment: @Warpzit Sort of agreed, if it's easier for SO to go through the process of obtaining parental permission and doing that within the legal requirements than it is to do this, then I agree with you. My estimate on that is different from yours (I would expect this to be much simpler), and for both of us, it's without having a complete overview of SO's architecture, so as far as I'm concerned, either one of us could be right.

Answer (score 1):

### Quality content posted by a previously underage user can be transferred to their new account

The key to this is to know the user ID of the original account, so the user should keep a link to their old user page, presumably one per site where they have content that should be salvaged. (If the user has a link to one of their old posts, the ID for that site can also be found there.)

See [Under age users - could they store their own data until of age?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351096/323179)