# Stack Overflow Kids

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

As technology advances more and more people are becoming interested in questions. Stack Overflow has become a giant 'stack' of all kinds of answers.

However, as more people come into Stack Overflow most tend to be questions that have already been asked. Thus I propose a new Idea. A kid friendly version of Stack Overflow. This version of Stack Overflow would allow young coders to ask questions without the currently hostile environment that the current Stack Overflow provides. *Stack Overflow Kids* would be for young adults (young teens) and for kids which would provide a different form of asking questions.

**Asking questions:**

- First asking a question would "post" which would then temporarily add the simple question on to the site.
- An answer would be prompted to the asker and the asker would answer yes or no to whether or not the answer was satisfactory.
- If it wasn't then the asker would be prompted to give a short explanation as to why. This explanation would then be appended to the question.
- Both asking and explaining would have a character limit.

**Answering Questions:**

- Questions are available to Stack Overflow users who, if they wish, can answer the question or send them an answer that has been previously given.

or

- The server will then try to match similar questions and then if the meaning of the question matches another question that has an answer then that answer would then be sent.

---

The questions that are answered would then be stored on the asker's computer. However, unique questions would be stored in a database.
Storing of prompts would be stored using a type of system.

- The question would first use a thesaurus to simplify the question

```
    Ex: [Java] How do I prevent an exception?
        To prevent an exception
    Action: Prevent -> Stop
    Applied: Exception
    - - - -
  Keys:
    Action: Stop
    Applied: Exception
```

**Pros**

- Less duplicated questions

**Cons**

- Takes resources
- Can't ask complicated questions

Comment: Looks that you are proposing a new site. This should be done at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This sounds similar to this proposal: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253646/create-a-new-stack-overflow-instance-for-beginner-users-and-content

Comment: Under 13 years old are not allowed on the stackoverflow network.  Probably because SO do not want to have deal with COPPA, and who can blame them.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to create a magic duplicate matching machine. Since you think this is ao easy, why don't you write it yourself. And then you can use it to apply gor a job with SO

Comment: how would answers be *"stored on the askers computer"* if said computer is turned off or re-imaged as per a network policy? don't forget that we are not all in the same time zone

Comment: i also fail to see how this will have less duplicated questions since how can the server find answers when they are stored locally on the asker's computer? the idea of a system to understand the meaning of a question and finding the duplicate and returning it's answers is a good theory which could itself be employed on Stack Exchange itself and if employed on SO, defeats the purpose of the new site, assuming of cause people bother to look at the duplicates (we already have suggested questions which alot of the time show the duplicates and no one reads them)

Comment: finally, your "Asking questions" section is what SO already does (minus the temporarily part). *"the asker would answer yes or no to whether or not the answer was satisfactory."* that's what accept, up and downvotes are for, *"If it wasn't then the asker would be prompted to give a short explanation as to why."* this is what editing and comments are for

Comment: Because we need paternalism and fragmentation.

Comment: Get outta my yard!

Comment: @Memor-X the site is supposed to be more friendly thus a down voting system is harder on the user

Comment: [HIGHLY related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320658/can-we-do-anything-better-about-users-under-13) (and an official word on why they probably won't do it ever)

Answer (score 23):

First off, it needs to be pointed out that United States law essentially forbids Stack Overflow from allowing users under the age of 13 to create accounts. (US law matters because that's where the company is based.) The only way that kids under 13 can use the site is if their parent creates and supervises their account. So, even if it would be useful, it is not really possible for us to create a "Stack Overflow Kids" for the youngest of programmers.

Second, I don't actually think that this would be beneficial. It suffers from the same fatal flaw as related proposals to create a "Stack Overflow for Beginners" (or "Novice Programmers", or whatever you want to call them). That flaw is, the website would become a virtual wasteland. Expert users would steer clear of it because it contains a smaller percentage of questions that they deem "interesting", and without the expert users there to audit and maintain the quality of the Q&A, intermediate users would begin to become suspect of its quality and therefore avoid it. After a relatively short time, it would consist *only* of kids (or novices, or whatever little group you were targeting), which essentially means that we would have a scenario where the blind are leading the blind. I don't say this to insult anyone, but rather to point out that the *benefit* ("killer feature", if you will) of Stack Overflow is our user base. We have some of the smartest, most capable programmers in the world here to offer advice themselves and audit the advice provided by others. If those people aren't there on "Stack Overflow Kids" (and I argue they wouldn't be), what would differentiate that site from any of the hundreds of other discussion forums that already exist out there on the web?

> **Asking Questions:**
>
> - First asking a question would "post" which would then temporarily add the simple question on to the site.
> - An Answer would be prompted to the asker and the asker would answer yes or no to whether or not the answer was satisfactory.
> - If it wasn't then the asker would be prompted to give a short explanation as to why. This explanation would then be appended to the question.

This is pretty much what we have now, except that questions are not added "temporarily" (and it's unclear to me how they are actually "temporary" in your proposed system, or what advantages that would have). Indicating whether an answer is "satisfactory" is already done via the acceptance checkmark, and explaining what part is unclear/insufficient is already done via the comment feature, which is always available to the asker on his/her own question.

The only thing that is really new there is to *automatically* append the explanation to the question. I suppose that might be a desirable feature, but if it's a winning idea, then it should be added to "Big Boy Stack Overflow", too.

> - Both asking and explaining would have a character limit.

This one is different…and I think a terrible idea. Partially because I've never been able to keep anything under a character limit, which would essentially prevent me from ever participating on such a site. But also because arbitrary limits just don't make sense.

> **Answering Questions:**
>
> - Questions are available to stack overflow users who, if they wish, can answer the question or send them an answer that has been previously given.

Again, we have this now. All questions that get posted to Stack Overflow are available to all Stack Overflow users, and if they wish, they can either answer them directly or they can flag them as a duplicate of a question that has already been answered.

> or
>
> - The server will then try to match similar questions and then if the meaning of the question matches another question that has a an answer then that answer would then be sent.

And again, this is the slightly new part of your proposal—a suggestion of an *automatic* duplicate-matching algorithm. If this were to be implemented, I don't see why we should limit it to "Stack Overflow Kids". It should be available on the main site, too. A rudimentary form of it already is, with the automatically-generated list of "related" questions, visible while you're composing a question. Anecdotally, people think that list is pretty good (usually better than what they're able to find with a search), so perhaps we should expand that further.

> The questions that are answered would then be stored on the askers computer. However, unique questions would be stored in a database.

What is the advantage of this? Why shouldn't useful content be publicly available to *everyone*? (It should.) Here is where I begin to wonder if perhaps you've misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow—or if perhaps you are proposing a site with a different and contradictory mission. Stack Overflow is not a help desk or tutorial site. We aren't here to teach people how to program. Our system just doesn't work for that, and we shouldn't try and *make* it work for that on a new "Stack Overflow Kids" site.

Comment: isn't asking/explaining in the form of a question already got a character limit? just that with the questions it's a very large one compared to comments?

Comment: Yeah, there is technically a character limit. I've never hit it before, though, so it's basically non-existent. It's just there to prevent abuse. Something like 30,000 characters. The only person I know that has ever hit it in normal use is Peter Cordes in his epic teach-you-everything-about-optimization-in-one-answer posts, and a lot of that is because of the full links to interactive demos on Godbolt Compiler Explorer. Still, generally a sign that you're writing a book rather than an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray the character limit is to differentiate between repeated questions and unique questions if a question needs a larger character limit and a detailed explanation then it probably should be on stack overflow not _Kids Stack overflow_. _Kids Stack Overflow_ is _"Ideally"_ meant for super simple questions. If someone (over 13) wants to ask a more complex question then they should do it on stack overflow using the stack overflow question guidelines. Also using the proposed system on Stack Overflow would not be as easy as a Question is to long to analyze for duplicates.

Comment: Why can't we just ask and answer the simple questions on regular Stack Overflow? Why do we need a separate place for them?

Comment: That way people wouldn't have to deal with simpler questions and if a question is fairly easy to be phased in a short sentence the question can be differed to _Kids Stack Overflow_ rather than experiencing the huge down votes or distain from the Community.

Comment: @merlindragonfire If they're *good questions* they aren't going to get downvotes on SO.  If they're bad questions *moving them somewhere else isn't fixing them*.

Comment: @Merlin Why are you even taking downvotes personal? Also, kids should learn how to ask questions properly.

Comment: @Chiel I don't mean to take this personally. I believe around the time of the post,I learned that stack overflow tends to downvote complicated questions.I also believe that part of the rules for asking questions is to not ask a question that has already been asked or that could be found by just typing it on google. I also after getting the question closed by the "community trash collector" bot, I asked a very simple question and received many upvotes from people, until moderators of the site closed the question for being open ended and simple. I was just thinking of a solution for this.

Comment: @Chiel Also I definitely agree with your statement that _kids should learn how to ask questions properly_ however think that a downvoting system which closes questions below -2(or -1) with no answers does not help children to learn how to ask questions. A better system would be maybe tell a child how to word a question, i guess. if moderators maybe would have the power to reset downvotes for some questions after edits. this may improve experience with new users.

Comment: @Merlin It appears you are a little upset about the downvotes. It are not complicated questions that get downvoted, but questions that lack attitude, or lack research invested in them. As I have said before, I still think you are taking it too personal, since you see it as something negative, instead of a mistake you should learn from. I know why people associate downvotes with negativity, but this is not the case. I have had serveral downvotes on some questions of mine, but I think people downvoting them eventually were right, so I deleted them.

Comment: @Merlin Now back to your question, do you really think your proposed system makes sense? Having duplicate questions all over the place being appended to a particular question doesn't make sense in any way since different questions have different contexts. Another reason is that SO already prevents users from asking duplicate questions by suggesting similar questions when users ask new questions. About the short answering; sure this is a good idea, but this is already possible within the current ecosystem.

Comment: @Chiel I apologize if I do seem a irritated. Sometimes when I am thinking, people tend to think I am angry. When I made this question, I may have been a bit bitter about my first question getting taken down as I felt that one of the reasons it got down-voted was because the problem was to complicated and specific and/or there was to much to read(because of it's specificity). Those that decided to help me fix the article I am thankful for that. It was even closed until I could reedit it. Once I did and added more info it was reopened and sat there. with -1 votes.

Comment: @Chiel But this was not what irritated me. It was that the site removed my post on Aug 6 '17 at 3:00  with the (RemoveAbandonedClosed) tag. I am not one to abandon a post. Esspecially If it is replied to as, what ever the message may be, I, at least as far as I can remember, am always glad that someone took the time to reply. I was even willing to answer my own question If I managed to ever find the answer.  I thought, and still think, that my question was a legitimate question to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Chiel I also think that, my question will likely not be able to be answered by Stack Overflow unless if I put a bounty on it. and the bounty would probably need to be a big one because, by the amount of effort I put into finding an answer, not many people would find one before giving up. Unless the developers of oracle's Netbeans IDE who developed the API happen come across it. I had relatively accepted the fact that Stack Overflow was essentially useless as a place to ask new questions. The only reason I use it is when google finds the answer I am looking for and it is linked to the site.

Comment: @Chiel sorry for getting back to you so late(years late). Tbh, I was just annoyed at how the ecosystem worked and wanted to try to come up with a solution. I was annoyed that it seemed like you couldn't ask a complex question on stackoverflow. Sadly the project will never be completed as I have lost interest in trying to even create it. Honestly, I think at the time, there was a general rift which made it hostile to ask questions. All the simple questions have been taken and ig it felt like people downvoted problems that were out of their comfort zone.

Comment: @merlin It may seem the case that all simple questions are "taken", and that people don't like answering questions outside of their comfort zone, but the reason for that is that questions should be formatted in a way that is minimal, reproducible and complete. This is because the question should not only be useful to the asker, but useful to the entire community. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Chiel yeah, saddly when I tried to reduce it, I got people telling me there wasn't enough info. It wasn't a fun time(I tried asking the question twice and people said it didn't have enough detail the second time I tried). Hopefully, nowadays people are nicer. The main reason that the minimal example was so large is because honestly, I was asking for help with using the API and wasn't able to create links at the time bc of low rank. The other problem is that I wanted to show my research to let people know that I had actually looked into it allot.