# Why does SO have a minimum age requirement?

Tags: discussion, support

Why do we have an minimum age requirement of 13? Wouldn't we want to encourage young kids to get learning quickly so they will be successful later on? What's the point? Security issues? Is this website too much for young children?

I read the Stack Overflow TOS: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age. It didn't give me a reason why there is a requirement.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow isn't necessarily a good place to "get learning quickly". It's a repository of high-quality questions and answers representing accumulated knowledge about practical programming problems. Can one learn from that? Sure. Would I recommend a <13 year old, new to programming, get their feet wet on Stack Overflow. My goodness no.

Comment: Don't know about that. Did fine on SO, racking up points (cause I was addicted) until I got banned. Im 13+ now, lol I don't need another ban.

Comment: It's very much *not* that we don't want to encourage young people to program. As the answer here states, 13 is a legal requirement in the USA, as is 16 in the EU. I don't know of anyone here who wouldn't encourage a young person to program, if the person is interested. It's unfortunate that young people below those ages must be excluded here, but compliance with the laws is mandatory.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-site duplicate, see [Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, or if I'm under 16 years old and from the EU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770)

Comment: Wow in the EU, u have to be 16+ to use SE? ...

Comment: @BuddyBobIII yeah, that's because of GDPR.

Comment: @bad_coder MSO questions shouldn't be closed as duplicates of MSE ones. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250073 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252289

Comment: @duplode none of the 2 posts you linked addresses closure of cross-site duplicate, [this one does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713).

Comment: @bad_coder The posts I linked address whether questions should be posted at MSO or MSE, which is the core issue here. The answer you suggest is older than [the MSO-MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888), so it doesn't apply quite as directly. (In any case, it also supports leaving this question open: "In the edge case where the question is appropriate on more than one site, leave it on both sites and let the users of each community benefit from the information".)

Comment: @duplode core issue is if cross-site duplicates should be closed for that reason, answer is yes.

Comment: @bad_coder The closure suggestion in Robert Cartaino's answer assumes that the question is inappropriate at the site in which it is being closed ("If a question is inappropriate on one site, users now have alternate places to go with it"). That is not the case here: questions that are relevant to how Stack Overflow works are on-topic on MSO even if they might apply to other parts of Stack Exchange, as the answers I linked to point out.

Comment: Is there one Site where a 13yo can post thing? Twitter, Facebook, Reddit all activelly ban 13. Even TikTok requires that users be at least 13 years old. You perhaps notice that everything where you can type text started to ask for your age? And more recently even game like amoung us banned free chat because of the age limitation.

Comment: Yoo, how is this off-topic?

Comment: Besides law, SO is pretty much a book; it is far away removed from being a school. Learn that fact quickly, don't treat SO as if it is a schooling environment designed to teach people things, you'll make all the wrong assumptions and choices. Whether someone learns something in the process of finding answers on SO is entirely up to them. Schools are better schools than websites.

Comment: Note that many platforms that have an age limit do not verify age in any way, except by asking the users. And if someone happened to not be truthful about their age, well, that would be their mistake, the legal part is done. And there's no real reason here to tell others your age.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we do anything better about users under 13?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320658/can-we-do-anything-better-about-users-under-13)

Comment: no, sorry it doesn't. The answer below does.

Comment: Why not? The proposed duplicate question explicitly mentions COPPA as mentioned in the answer below, and the answer says *"We're not allowed to collect and store any personally-identifying information about minors under the age of 13 without explicit parental consent."* - That's all the below answer amounts to, if the below answer answers your question, so does the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Young programmers still can read here. They can learn a lot from reading alone.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because [COPPA](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule).

Fundamentally speaking, Stack Overflow is based in the United States, and the United States has passed a federal law prohibiting companies from knowingly collecting any data from any users who claim to be under 13 years of age, no matter where those individuals are in the world, along with a strict requirement to remove any data that can be traced back to someone who is 13 years or younger.

Comment: What never makes sense to me is that they don't consider a 14 year old to be a "child". I know it's the law, but it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: you can get a job at 14.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiniuaX7ervAhWHJTQIHQFGCKAQFjACegQIBxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thebalanceeveryday.com%2Flegal-working-age-in-california-2085387&usg=AOvVaw2eRekuFD_z7-ihkNcDwrYe

Comment: And GDPR in the EU and certain Schengen-countries makes the requirement 16 instead of 13.

Comment: I have read COPPA applies everywhere, no matter it is passed in America.

Comment: They should include this in the Terms of Service.

Comment: @Anonymous: [They already do](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age)

Comment: @Makoto I meant the reasoning should be included, as the question states they simply tell you it's not allowed without telling us why.

Comment: @Anonymous:  I don't really think that they *have* to explain why they're prohibiting users under 13 (and in Europe, users under 16).  Terms aren't two-way streets; there are clear allowances and prohibitions, and the reason for why this is could boil down to, "because I said so" and that'd be unsatisfactory for a multitude of reasons.  If nothing else, the inquisitive among you would also piece together that pretty much *every* site has a minimum age requirement of 13 and that this *probably* isn't some arbitrary thing.

Comment: @10Rep According to the FTC’s FAQ for COPPA, they do think there should be something protecting teens but they want something more flexible than COPPA. But that was back in 2012: https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions-0#A.%20General%20Questions

Comment: There's an interesting point. Somebody under 13 definitely shouldn't register in Stack Overflow. However, under appropiate parental or teacher guidance, it would be somewhat interesting to allow them _browsing_ questions in this website as a guest, since this is definitely a large knowledge base and a great learning tool. Per current TOS, this is forbidden. Likely due to tracking and data collection happening regardless of registration. The modern era Internet...

Comment: Thing is @MarcSances, if Stack Overflow then learns that they've collected data on someone who's younger than 13, they have to take immediate steps to delete that data, which is pretty labor intensive depending on a number of factors.  I don't disagree that younger programmers in middle/secondary school could benefit from looking at the site, but the law doesn't make for allowances and is pretty clear on this matter.